# ffmpeg Installation Error Through Homebrew

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I was looking to download ffmpeg to convert some mp4/mp3 files in python but was met with an error I could not find the solution for elsewhere.

When attempting to install ffmpeg on terminal, I was met by this error.

`fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision Warning: No available formula with the name "ffmpeg". ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found. ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Error: No previously deleted formula found. ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps.`

I was expecting everything to work perfectly but obviously it hasn't. I looked into other users that had similar errors and went through what they did to solve their problems but was not able get anything to work out.

Comment: Have you done `brew update` and `brew doctor` recently?

Comment: After downloading the ffmpeg tool, can you try it from the terminal?  dowland [link](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [apple.se] would be better places for questions like this.